# Partition table before installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt, grub-efi

when installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode alongside Windows 10 I don't know what the partition table should look like.  After this image:

[image]

what options will be presented?  Assuming no recovery partition for Windows, just that the whole drive is partitioned for Windows 10 with GPT and UEFI.

The [WindowsDualBoot directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) specify:

```
Manual partitioning

    Choose "Manually edit partition table".
    Listed will be your current partitions.
    Select the partition you want to resize and press Enter.
    Select "Size:", press Enter.
    Select Yes, press Enter.
    Type in a new size in gigabytes for your partition, it's recommended you free up at least 10 GB of free space for your Ubuntu install. Press Enter when happy with your changes. It may take some time to apply the changes.

    Create a swap partition of at least your amount of RAM (if you don't know, 8000 MB is a good value).
    Create a partition for your Ubuntu installation.

    Create other partitions if necessary: see DiskSpace
    Select "Finish partitioning and write changes to disk".
```

before I install what should the disk look like from `fdisk` or similar?  On my system `lsblk` shows:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo lsblk 
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 74.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 74.1G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:0    0   72G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
thufir@doge:~$
```

but before I press the button to install **alongside** Windows 10, what **should** it look like from `fdisk` or similar?  Assuming UEFI and GPT and that Windows 10 is on the first partition.

GPT:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

and UEFI:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit at [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) to find help on dual boot Ubuntu.

The partition table will look like

[image: screen shot of partition table]

Comment: would you add comments for sda[1-n] for what those are?  Is sda1 GPT?

Comment: sda 1 - windows boot loader, sda 2 - Windows 10, sda 3 - ext for Ubuntu install , sda 5 -  mount = / , sda 6 - swap area, sda 7 - home partition

Comment: ok, leaving open for a bit, but that seems to answer the question.  Thanks.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help people.

Answer (score 1):

Install ubuntu normally on another drive, allow the grub installer to take over the windows one.

After you're done normally you will not see windows being installed, don't worry it's common.

Input the following command once you boot up your ubuntu system.

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will now try to list all the installed OS's in your hard disk.

The text should be as follows

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

Next time you're booting up your PC, you will be able to see windows listed in your grub loader

PS: What I mentioned is best applicable when you choose something else and you install ubuntu on a separate formatted drive without touching the windows drive.

Comment: pardon, not an option to install on another drive (unless you count external USB flash) because it's a laptop.  Just the one drive.

Comment: when I said drive I meant partition, not actual physical disk. Ex: C: Drive, D: Drive, etc...

Comment: there are a multitude of questions relating to different windows versions, UEFI and GPT.  No answer yet details what the partition table should look like before installing Linux that I see.

Comment: @Thufir  for me it worked with both types [UEFI & GPT], I formatted the extra drive in ext4 and set the boot to the root.

Comment: @Thufir whenever I ran into trouble with either windows or ubuntu missing I'd revert to Boot-Repair  to fix the issue for me after following the mentioned steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: my concern with what your saying is precision about "drive" versus "partition" in your answer.  Because it's Windows there just seem so many ways to bork the system causing catastrophic data loss.

Comment: @Thufir Okay, so personally I free up a 100 GB partition and format it which i separate into its own letter from "Disk Management" to be sure that i don't mess up anything i make sure that value is unique (partition size) i go into ubuntu's [Something else] and find that partition then reformat it again into ext4, this way no matter what happens all my other partitions are safe even if the bootloader gets removed, i can recover it with the boot repair that i mentioned in case of a bad installation.

Comment: @Thufir hope my answer got your dual boot system working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49971/discussion-between-thufir-and-newbie).